# python-operate matrix with characters

Tags: python, numpy, types

Let's say I have a table with characters and want to operate over numbers:

```
import numpy
pru=numpy.matrix([['a', 'a','w','a'],[1, 2,4,5],[3, 4,1,2]])

type(pru)
```

> numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

```
a=pru[1:3,0]
b=a - a[0]
```

I get the following error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'matrix' and 'matrix'

But if I create another matrix ecluding the characters, I can do the substraction, but the "type" of the object is still the same:

```
pru=numpy.matrix([[1, 2,4,5],[3, 4,1,2]])
type(pru)
```

> numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix

```
a=pru[:,0]
b=a - a[0]
```

And I get the right result.

So to convert it to float I do:

```
a=a.astype(float)
```

But I don't want to be converting each part of the element everytime I need it. I want to have different types of elements in one object (like data.frames in R). Is this possible in Python?

Comment: Are you sure `a=pru[:1:3,0]` is doing what you think/want? Is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add *numpy.object*, like so :

```
pru=numpy.matrix([['a', 'a','w','a'],[1, 2,4,5],[3, 4,1,2]], dtype=numpy.object)
```

And then :

```
a=pru[1:3,0]
print a - a[0]
```

It prints :

```
matrix([[0],
        [2]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a data-frame object in Python, you should be using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), not numpy.
That will give you better support for labeled rows and columns and allow for easier mixing of data types.
In Pandas, columns of the same type are what is stored, so I've transposed your data to put each data type along each column.
Here's what this operation would look like in pandas:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
pru = DataFrame([['a', 1, 3], ['a', 2, 4], ['w', 4, 1], ['a', 5, 2]])
a = pru[[1,2]].ix[0]
b = a - a[1]
b
```

Also, when using numpy, you'll often find that the interface for the ndarray class is much more well-developed and well-maintained than the matrix class.
If you'd like to make an array that contains composite types, you can use numpy's [dtype system](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).